# Nginx failed test version 1010002 instead of 1012000 in /usr/share/nginx/modules/mod-http-image-filter.conf

Tags: nginx

Upgraded nginx on a centos 6 test system from 1.10.x to 1.12.x via yum update.  I then followed steps to get GeoIP module working (https://tushev.org/articles/linux-bsd/32/using-dynamic-geoip-module-with-nginx-centos).

When I run nginx -t, the following error is displayed:

```
$ nginx -t
nginx: [emerg] module "/usr/lib64/nginx/modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so" version 1010002 instead of 1012000 in /usr/share/nginx/modules/mod-http-image-filter.conf:1
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

In my nginx.conf file I commented out the line below

```
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;
```

and nginx worked as expected again.  That's great but doesn't solve my problem.  Since this is a dev environment I need to get this working 100%.  I am unsure that I really need the image filter after reading the specs (http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_image_filter_module.html).

Further, I did add individual modules back with luck as well:

```
load_module "modules/ngx_http_geoip_module.so";
```

I would like to know how to solve the version issue that the error displays and to know if omitting these modules, outside of the one I want, is okay?

Thank you for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 24):

Posting another solution for people having similar problems, running these following commands worked for me on Centos 7 after I had already [configured `yum` to look to the latest version](https://www.prado.lt/5-minute-upgrade-nginx-1-12-to-1-17-on-centos-7-rhel-7):

```
sudo yum remove nginx-mod*
sudo yum install nginx-module-*
```

[Here are some more details](https://nopistash.wordpress.com/2018/05/03/centos7-nginx-conflicting-module-versions/)

Comment: Upgraded from 1.16 to 1.20 and restarting the nginx service fails with the OP error. Removing the offending 1.16 modules seemed to fix the issue but when I tried to install `nginx-module-*` I got the error `No package nginx-module-* available.`

Comment: this worked for me @ RHEL8.5 updating nginx from 1.14 to 1.20

Comment: it worked in Oracle Linux 8.6, nginx from 1.14 to 1.23.2

Answer (score 4):

In case Someone face the same problem i invite him to follow these steps to resolve the issues of the compatibility:

before making the module ngx_http_modsecurity_module.so that needed to be load in 
nginx.conf config file under /etc/nginx/nginx.config.

`load_module modules/ngx_http_modsecurity_module.so;`

1. perform version check against your pre-installed nginx
  `$ nginx -v`
  in my case
  **`nginx version: nginx/1.15.10 `**
2. download the same version
  **`$ wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.15.10.tar.gz`**
3. $ tar zxvf nginx-1.15.10.tar.gz
4. $ cd nginx-1.15.10
5. $ ./configure --with-compat --add-dynamic-module=/path_to_your/modsecurity-nginx-connector
6. $ cp objs/ngx_http_modsecurity_module.so /etc/nginx/modules
7. add the module to nginx at the beginning of the /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file, after the `user` directive
  **`load_module modules/ngx_http_modsecurity_module.so;`**
8. $ nginx -t
  **`nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok 

  nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful `**

and continue the process... as described here [nginx.org](https://www.nginx.com/blog/compiling-and-installing-modsecurity-for-open-source-nginx/)
hope im helpful.

Comment: A blog post I've found later (which is for Brotli, but could've been changed to any other dynamic module) is https://www.majlovesreg.one/adding-brotli-to-a-built-nginx-instance The script works pretty well in upgrading the dynamic module after upgrading an already existing nginx (e.g. 1.17.10 to 1.18.0 will give the version mismatch).

Comment: I'm confused on5. - path_to_your/modsecurity-nginx-connector
I just have a vanilla nginx installed in /etc/  - there's no mention of modsecurity...

Answer (score 4):

Same problem after updating Nginx from version 1.16.1 to 1.20.1:

```bash
# yum update nginx
...
Updated:
  nginx.x86_64 1:1.20.1-9.el7

Dependency Updated:
  nginx-filesystem.noarch 1:1.20.1-9.el7

Complete!

# nginx -t
nginx: [emerg] module "/usr/lib64/nginx/modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so" version 1016001 instead of 1020001 in /usr/share/nginx/modules/mod-http-image-filter.conf:1
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Based on the comment of Syd Lambert https://stackoverflow.com/a/58108125/13088275

It is not necessary to delete and reinstall Nginx modules but instead update them:

```bash
# yum update nginx*
Updated:
  nginx-all-modules.noarch 1:1.20.1-9.el7   nginx-mod-http-image-filter.x86_64 1:1.20.1-9.el7   nginx-mod-http-perl.x86_64 1:1.20.1-9.el7   nginx-mod-http-xslt-filter.x86_64 1:1.20.1-9.el7
  nginx-mod-mail.x86_64 1:1.20.1-9.el7      nginx-mod-stream.x86_64 1:1.20.1-9.el7

Complete!
```

After updating all Nginx modules, Nginx test was successful and I can safe reload Nginx.

```bash
# nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

# nginx -s reload
```

So the best way to update Nginx is to use the command `yum update nginx*`.

Answer (score 2):

Rollback to 1.10.2.

`nginx: [emerg] module "/etc/nginx/modules/ngx_http_geoip_module.so" version 1010002 instead of 1013002 in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:12
nginx version: nginx/1.13.2`

Answer (score 1):

I found that I needed to obliterate *all* the previous nginx-related files `rm -rf /etc/nginx` and then after another `make install` everything checked out.

Answer (score 0):

I just backed up my .conf files then uninstalled and reinstalled nginx and it was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

my problem here is

```
sudo nginx -t
2021/07/22 16:54:54 [emerg] 2637399#2637399: module "/usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_http_geoip2_module.so" version 1020001 instead of 1020000 in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

This means my `ngx_http_geoip2_module` module version is not matched with my Nginx version.
Since I just installed `ngx_http_geoip2_module` latest version, it must be my Nginx version that needs to update.

Upgrade Nginx version fixed my problem

Answer (score 0):

This issue occured because when Nginx was updated, it did not update it’s modules along side it. You will need to manually update these modules to get Nginx up again.

Updating the modules is pretty straight forward, you simply need to update one of them and the rest come along as dependancies. To do update, issue the following:

```
yum update nginx-mod-http-image-filter
```

Restart Nginx now and that’s it.

```
service nginx restart
```

Links:
https://www.theshell.guru/nginx-version-mismatch/